# Strongly typed IDs with generic class

Tags: c#, generics, strong-typing

I want to change some of my entities IDs to strongly typed. And in order to avoid too much code refactoring I used implicit conversions.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class FooBarId
{
    private readonly Guid _id;

    public FooBarId(Guid id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public static implicit operator Guid(FooBarId id)
    {
        return id.Id;
    }

    public static implicit operator FooBarId(Guid id)
    {
        return new FooBarId(id);
    }
}
```

This code works fine and I don't have to change anything else in my code.

But I would like to create much more such classes and in order to avoid repeating myself I created a generic class:

```
public class CustomId<T>
{
    private readonly T _id;

    public CustomId(T id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public T Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(CustomId<T> id)
    {
        return id.Id;
    }

    public static implicit operator CustomId<T>(T id)
    {
        return new CustomId<T>(id);
    }
}
```

And tried to inherit it in my `FooBarId` class:

```
public class FooBarId : CustomId<Guid>
{
}
```

And then my code breaks with an exception where FooBarId is used:

`Argument type 'System.Guid' is not assignable to parameter type 'FooBarId'`.

When I try to cast it like this `foo.bar((FooBarId)new Guid())` - code compiles, but throws an exception later in program execution:

`<System.InvalidCastException> (Unable to cast object of type 'CustomId1[System.Guid]' to type 'FooBarId'.)`

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: What code are you using to get _an exception where FooBarId is used_?

Comment: @Trisped I call some command method, which accepts FooBarId as a parameter: `foo.bar((FooBarId)new Guid())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guid result1 = (CustomId<Guid>)new CustomId<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid());
        Guid result2 = (CustomId<Guid>)new FooBarId();
        Guid result3 = (FooBarId)new FooBarId();
        Guid result4 = new FooBarId();

        CustomId<Guid> cIResult = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class CustomId<T>
{
    private readonly T _id;

    public CustomId(T id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public T Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(CustomId<T> id)
    {
        return id.Id;
    }

    public static implicit operator CustomId<T>(T id)
    {
        return new CustomId<T>(id);
    }
}

public class FooBarId : CustomId<Guid>
{
    public FooBarId()
        : base(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }
}
```

You cannot do `(FooBarId)new Guid()` because a `CustomId<Guid>` is not a `FooBarId`.  You will need to define am implicit operator for each class which converts from [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) to that class.

Comment: The reason why I wanted to create that generic class is to save some lines of code by not defining implicit conversions in each ID classes and having that only in generic class. But if that's not possible, then I guess I don't need that generic class at all. Thank you for help.